# Как определить высоту клика?

Tags: jquery, html

Есть див с определенной высотой. Есть ли возможность на jQuery определить, на какой высоте в диве был сделан клик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("someSelector").on('click', function( e ) {
  var clickHeight = e.offsetY;
  // +, как можно было догадаться
  var clickWidth = e.offsetX;
})
```

Comment: Не получилось=(

    $('#cont1').on('click', function( e ) {
        var clickHeight = e.offsetY;
        $('#cont1').val(clickHeight);
    });

Comment: Как получить значения я написал, если хотите убедится в их работоспособности - сделайте console.log или alert, в остальном разбирайтесь сами

Comment: Это я перемудрил с выводом значения просто..А что такое console.log ?

Comment: ну погуглите же, разве не очевидно? вывод в консоль

Answer (score 1):

```
$("someSelector").click(function(e){
var h=e.currentTarget.offsetHeight + e.currentTarget.offsetTop-e.clientY;
alert(h);
});
```

здесь `offsetHeight` - высота блока, `offsetTop` - верхняя точка блока на странице, `clientY` - координаты мышки на момент клика.